# How to get the timestamp when the user gives an input in C

Tags: c, loops, time

I've got 2 problems.

1. How can I make a loop that will keep getting input from user unless he enters a specific input — in my case it's `exit`.
2. I need to write the timestamp of the input in a file but I am not that familiar with C.

I need something to loop like this

```
        if (strcmp(userInput, quit) == 0 ) {
            exit(1);
        } else {
            printf("IS IT IN?!");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function you can use to print the current time in the format "HH:MM:SS AM/PM".

```
void printCurrentTime()
{
   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm* timeinfo;
   char buffer[100];

   time (&rawtime);
   timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

   strftime (buffer, 100, "%I:%M:%S %p", timeinfo);
   printf("Current time: %s.\n", buffer);
}
```

The looping can be accomplished using:

```
while (1)
{
    if ( NULL == fgets (useInput, maximumLineLength, stdin))
    {
       exit(1);
    }
    if ( strcmp(useInput, quit) == 0 )
    {
       exit(1);
    }
    printCurrentTime();
}
```

Comment: The `%I` and `%p` formats should only be used under duress; they make parsing the output data unnecessarily hard.  Don't forget, 12:15 A.M. comes long before 11:15 A.M.  Use 24-hour clock notation, not 12-hour (so `%H:%M:%S`).